# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Unspecified error at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2014

I get an exception on trying to fire a stored procedure and fill a dataset using the below method

```
OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(Dataset ds)
```

Please note that this exception occurs only for large tables with millions of rows, for smaller tables it works fine.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Unspecified error
>       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)

Comment: are the columns name same as the column names of the table in the database?

Comment: maybe a bit of code surrounding that line would help us?

Comment: & also screenshot of the error